# How can I get input as an empty string?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>    
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    getline(cin, s);
    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I think it will help someone with my question and answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: You forgot to `#include <string>`.

Comment: #include <bits/stdc++.h>
including this header file all necessary header file has been included.

Answer (score 2):

In the code you showed, I think pressing only the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will return an empty string.